# How to have a translucent window, but opaque text?

Tags: python, windows, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am trying to make a window that is translucent, but has opaque text. My OS is Windows, and I don't care about cross-platform support. I am relatively new to python, and especially new to tkinter, so don't expect me to know everything. I am using `attributes('-alpha', transparency)` for the translucent window, which I believe may be a problem. I am using a canvas to add the text, and the window has no topbar/window decorations.
I have looked all over, and only found ways to make the background 100 percent transparent with opaque text. If tkinter is not the best library to use for what I am doing, please let me know as I will definitely switch libraries. Same goes for the programming language too.

Here is my code:

```py
import tkinter as tk

class DraggableWindow(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, master=None, width=300, height=200, transparency=0.75, bg_color="white", text="New window",
                 text_color='black', text_size=12, text_font=('Arial', 12)):
        super().__init__(master)

        # Default window properties
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.transparency = transparency
        self.bg_color = bg_color
        self.border_radius = 0

        # Text properties
        self.text_content = text
        self.text_color = text_color
        self.text_size = text_size
        self.text_font = text_font

        # Set window attributes
        self.overrideredirect(True)  # Remove window decorations
        self.geometry(f'{self.width}x{self.height}')  # Set initial size
        self.attributes('-alpha', self.transparency)  # Set initial transparency

        # Create a canvas to hold widgets
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, bg=self.bg_color, bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
        self.canvas.pack(expand=True, fill='both')

        # Create a text widget on the canvas
        self.text_id = self.canvas.create_text(
            self.width // 2, self.height // 2,
            text=self.text_content,
            fill=self.text_color,
            font=self.text_font,
            anchor='center'
        )

        # Bind events for dragging the window
        self.canvas.bind('<ButtonPress-1>', self.start_drag)
        self.canvas.bind('<B1-Motion>', self.on_drag)

        # Track whether the window is on top
        self.on_top = False

        # Create a context menu
        self.context_menu = tk.Menu(self, tearoff=0)
        self.context_menu.add_command(label='Settings', command=self.show_settings)
        self.context_menu.add_command(label='Hide', command=self.hide_window)
        self.context_menu.add_command(label='Close', command=self.close_window)
        self.context_menu.add_command(label='Remove', command=self.remove_window)

        # Bind the context menu to the right-click event
        self.bind('<Button-3>', self.show_context_menu)

    def start_drag(self, event):
        self.start_x = event.x_root
        self.start_y = event.y_root

    def on_drag(self, event):
        deltax = event.x_root - self.start_x
        deltay = event.y_root - self.start_y
        x = self.winfo_x() + deltax
        y = self.winfo_y() + deltay

        # Update start coordinates for the next drag event
        self.start_x = event.x_root
        self.start_y = event.y_root

        self.geometry(f'{self.width}x{self.height}+{x}+{y}')

    def toggle_topmost(self):
        self.on_top = not self.on_top
        self.attributes('-topmost', self.on_top)

    def show_settings(self):
        # Implement settings functionality later
        print('Settings clicked')

    def hide_window(self):
        self.withdraw()  # Hide the window

    def close_window(self):
        self.destroy()  # Close the white window

    def remove_window(self):
        self.destroy()  # Remove the white window from the GUI

    def show_context_menu(self, event):
        # Display the context menu at the right-click position
        self.context_menu.post(event.x_root, event.y_root)

def create_window(master, **kwargs):
    window = DraggableWindow(master, **kwargs)
    window.toggle_topmost()  # Set initial state
    return window

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = tk.Tk()
    app.withdraw()  # Hide the default main window

    window1 = create_window(app, width=300, height=200, text="Window 1", transparency=1)
    window2 = create_window(app, width=400, height=300, text="Window 2", text_color='red', bg_color="black", transparency=0.1)

    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Try Googling "tkinter transparent colour". More specifically `.attributes("-transparentcolor", "white")` makes all white pixels on the window transparent.

Comment: @TheLizzzard That makes a 100% transparent color. I wanted some transparency, not all

Comment: As far as I know, that and `.attributes('-alpha', ...)` are your only options that use `tkinter`. You can make 2 windows, one with the `transparentcolor` and one with the `alpha` and layer them on top of each other but that will be a pain to code. Apart from that you can switch GUI frameworks or try looking for the appropriate WIN API calls.